# Using NIO Http Connector in Tomcat 7 - its limiting me to one connection?

Tags: tomcat, nio

I want to make a service that basically holds a connection till a second connection is made to tell it to stop holding the first one.

Using NIO Http Connector with all default settings (in Tomcat and the connector).

I use a thread (much like the "messageSender" class in the tomcat aio doc) to hold the first response and write/flush a character every 5 seconds. This is working fine - the thread holds it and releases it on cue. The only problem is that the service ('event' method) does not get a second call (for the second connection's 'begin' event) till I close the first connection.

So to repeat, this is what happens:

connection 1 - > tomcat creates thread 'http-nio-8081-exec-2' which calls myService.event(event);

myService.event gives the response to 'myDaemonThread' (which holds the reference and writes to the response every 5 seconds). exits method.

'myDaemonThread' uses "synchronized (this){ this.wait(5000); }" for waiting (initially used Thread.sleep() but in an attempt to make this work, I changed to wait() )

connection 2 - > initiated but no thread calls myService.event

connection 1 is stopped in the browser, tomcat creates thread 'http-nio-8081-exec-4' which calls myService.event(event.END). exits method.

tomcat (creates ?? now or earlier, cant tell) thread 'http-nio-8081-exec-6' calls myService.event(event.BEGIN) for connection two.

...... the rest is unimportant.

So this seems to defeat the entire purpose of using NIO... anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Why? If you're starting a thread and then just waiting for it to complete, why not just run the method that the thread runs? And why do you want to keep the connection open for 5 seconds in the first place?

Comment: Without seeing some actual code it is impossible to determine what you doing wrongly.

Comment: I went through such lengths to describe what was happening exactly because you dont need the code to solve this. This was (I suspected) a Tomcat/Comet (settings) based problem - not code based, though I suppose I should have said as much.

Answer (score 1):

### Possible Reasons

1. Tomcat isn't allowing two identical request from the same client at the same time
2. The client queues identical requests 'behind the scenes'.

Whatever, the result is, if I change the client for the second request, everything worked fine. If I added junk parameters to the second request on the same client, it worked fine.

### Solution

Add junk params to the requests

Comment: just stumbled across this post and can't research ti in detail, but in the back of my mind something says this might be an underlying restriction of the http protocol definition....

Comment: I upvoted. I've been struggling hard to make it work in my app. The so called Comet that use service streaming doesn't work even after I enabled NIO and I'm glad I found this page. I will try this tomorrow, to pass junk parameters to each request.

Comment: I've seen this in other places too.  Like Safari on iPad where it would automatically cache identical requests.  Even outgoing.  Putting random garbage in the request helped.

Comment: I didn't think that this could be the client browser queuing requests. It wouldn't be caching, in this case at least, since the second connection does get made. Actually, the browser queuing this makes a lot of sense.